# Error in mixing C and C++ codes in zeromq example

Tags: c++, c, zeromq

I wish to write zeromq in C++, therefore I'm trying to compile Freelance model 3 by mixing the C with C++ codes, which uses the freelance client API (flcliapi.c). I have zmq, czmq and cppzmq installed.

I created an empty program to include the header:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zmsg.hpp>
#include <flcliapi.h>
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile this with gcc and g++ using the following script:

```
gcc -c flcliapi.c -o flcliapi.o
g++ -c client.cpp -o client.o
g++ -o client flcliapi.o client.o -lzmq -lczmq
```

but I got the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/zmonitor.h:50: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/flcliapi.h:25: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
```

I've tried to remove some of the headers or compile methods, but this doesn't fix the error. How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the offending header files? Anything unusual there?

Comment: You'll need to show us the offending header files.  But I don't think trying to include a C++ header in C source is a good idea.  Also beware you'll need to declare your C functions as `extern "C"` when reading their header file prototypes in C++ mode, so that g++ knows to refer to them by *unmangled* names when trying to call C from C++.

Comment: I have looked into the two headers, the declaration of functions have no problem. They both return zmsg_t *, I wonder if the problem happens  somewhere else.